# How to prove n>0⟹n≥1 for integers n by constructing a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How to prove $n>0\implies n\ge1$ for integers $n$ by constructing a truth table?

I know the some basic concepts of the truth tables like $p,q,r$ but I have no idea how to prove the above statement true using a truth table.

```
      p     q     r
      T     T     T 
      T     T     F
      T     F     T
      T     F     F
      F     T     T
      F     T     F
      F     F     T
      F     F     F
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit of a rant, and isn't particularly helpful. $$\,$$ I don't like when exercises are of the form "solve X using Y", because I think that if X is appropriately chosen, then it should be clear why Y is a good choice for the solution. In this case, the X is chosen so that the Y, "prove using truth tables", is a very silly requirement. $$\,$$ In fact, I'm not sure that there is any choice of X that makes "prove using truth tables" a useful technique. I doubt anybody has achieved anything productive via a truth table proof.

Comment: The book that the OP provides a link to in a comment below does show truth tables that include assignments to term variables, but in a way that makes sense in context. The OP's question doesn't seem to relate to the problems in the book, so I am voting to close to encourage the OP to fix this question.

Comment: "The OP's question doesn't seem to relate to the problems in the book"  It is problem 2..2.

Comment: @fleablood: my comment was correct at the time I wrote it. The OP had provided a page reference to the book that was wrong and has subsequently corrected this in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the book asks you to do this by *exhausting* all possible values of $n \in \mathbb Z$.

$\begin{cases}n&||& n > 0 & n \ge 1 &  (n>0)\implies (n\ge 1) \\\\n < 0&||& F & F & T\\ n=0&||& F & F & T\\n = 1&||& T & T & T\\ n>1&||& T & T & T\\\end{cases}$

If you like you can combine lines 1 and 2 with $n \le 0$ and lines 2 and 3 with $n \ge 1$.

===

That's a weird question:  I can only suppose it is meant to be so thusly:

$\begin{cases} n > 0 & n \ge 1 & \text{is this possible?} & (n>0)\implies (n\ge 1) \\ T & T&\text {yes} & T\\ \color{red}T & \color{red}F & \color{red}{\text{no}}& \color{red}F\\ \color{red}F&\color{red}T&\color{red}{\text{no}}& \color{red}T\\ F&F&\text{yes} & T\end{cases}$

So the only case where $(n>0)\implies (n\ge 1)$ could be false,  (If $n > 0$ is true and $n\ge 1$ is false) is impossible (because $n \not \ge 1 \implies n <1  \implies n \le 0\implies n \not > 0$) so of all the rest of the possible options  (and one of the *im*possible ones) $(n>0)\implies (n\ge 1)$ is true.

If this feels silly and slightly circular and as though you are assuming what you have to prove mathematically before you prove it in pure logic.... well, I agree....

Comment: The question does not appear on page 9 in the book you link to. Please fix your question. In the meantime, I vote to close.

Comment: This is from the book [An Introduction to mathematical resoning](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nige/IMRpartI.pdf) Page No.20

Comment: You should follow the example on page 11.

Comment: While you're probably right something like this may be the intended interpretation, I would say it _is_ as silly as it looks. For example, filling out the last line of your first table requires you to _already know_ that, say, $n>1\Rightarrow  n>0$, which is not less deserving of proof than the implication we're ostensibly proving.

Comment: Yeah.... I kind of agree.  But then again ... not quite.  It requires you to know that $n > 1$ can only happen if $n > 0$ but you don't know that that is what the statement $n >1 \implies n > 0$ means.  But... it bugs me that it assume intuitive grasp of reasoning that are *more* complicated than the reasoning to be proven.  Kind of.  Or that you know math before you prove statements about math.  And...yeah... One can argue the ability to classify numbers is an advanced concept needing proving.  Not going to be my favorite book.  I'll have to read more to critique.

Comment: Yeah.... they are teaching the logic but assuming you know the (extremely basic) math to begin with.  But to know the math you must prove it with logic and definition and ... these are *terrible* examples and set a bad precedence.  It introduces trichotomy and transitivity of inequality on page 24 but assumes you can state that integers can be grouped in 4 categories and that $a>b;b>c$ imple $a>c$ and if that $1 > 0$ in the first place on page 20.  Not going to be my favorite book, not going to be my favorite book.

Comment: @fleablood: my close vote stands. If the OP can't identify the right page in the book that's causing the problem, we are all wasting our time until the question (and not just the associated comments)  are fixed.

Comment: "my close vote stands. " not arguing with that.  This is a rather weird question as it does require the context of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Truth tables really are just for proving tautologies with statements, i.e. things with a true/false value. That way you can enumerate all possibilities, and verify that they are true in all situations.

In this case, we're dealing with a predicate in $n$. To enumerate all possibilities, you would have to list all integers $n$, and assign a true/false label to the statement to each of them. This, of course, would have to be some kind of infinite table, of which we'd only be able to see a finite number of rows anyway, which defeats the purpose of a truth table, in that you're able to see that the statement is always true.

So, basically, you cannot prove this with a truth table.

Comment: In the context of the book in is okay to make a list of $n < 0; n = 0; n = 1; n > 1$.  It's not as silly as I first thought.  (See http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nige/IMRpartI.pdf page 11) for an example.

Comment: Although it's "not as silly as I first thought" it is in no way going to become my favorite book any time soon.